# How to set formatter programmatically?

Tags: django, logging, formatter, django-1.8

I am trying to format my logger, for which I defined a formatter in the settings life. However I cannot manage to figure out how to set it as the logger's handler's formatter:

```
def mylogger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(logger_path, 'w')
    handler.setFormatter(?????)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

Note I need to do this programmatically. I can't declare the handler in the setting file because `RotatingFileHandler` may need to be passed some additional arguments.

So the question is: in `handler.setFormatter(?????)` how do I get the formatter (by name, for example, just how loggers are retrieved) I defined in the settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logger_path, 'w')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-12s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')  
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Documentation can be found here: [**`formatter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects), [**`setFormatter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setFormatter).